# Background size : contain

Tags: html, css

I would like a div with a background-image that keeps the aspect ratio of the image, with a fixed height of 500px and i want no "padding" on the background of that div.
Is this possible to do?

I Can get a div with a fixed height and a background-image that keeps aspect ratio :

```
  <div style="background: url(something.png) 50% 50% / cover #D6D6D6;background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;height:500px"></div>
```

This makes the image centered in the middle of the div ( either vertically or horizontally ) but gives some padding to the background of the div ...

Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: You need to show us the original image to confirm that the space is not caused by the padding that is already in the image.

Comment: Does it matter if some part of the image is not visible/cropped? If you remove the `background-size:contain` property you will see that the image will always take up all of the `div` since you have added `cover` in the `background` property.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Made sure on multiple images, it is not caused by padding that is already on image

Comment: @phpheini Yes it matters, i want to keep all of the image and in its aspect ratio

Comment: @Jackymamouth So basically what you want is the surrounding `div` to have the same width as the image, don't you?

Comment: @phpheini Yes exactly

Comment: What's the look you are going for? If you want the div to match the dimensions of the image in pure css and html you'll need to use the image as content and not a background. You can then position other elements like text over the image using absolute. 

If you don't want to do that you can use javascript to find the width of the background-image, then assign that width to the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible using only CSS, you could use JavaScript to detect the width of the image and then set the width of the `div` to be the same. Or alternatively you could simply remove the `background-image` property and rather add the image as an `img` tag into your HTML. If you do that you can display the `div` as `inline-block` which will take care of making the `div` as wide as the width of the image.

```css
body
{
  text-align:center;
}
div
{
  background-color:#666;
  display:inline-block;
}
div img
{
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/500" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`background-size: contain;` will always display the *whole* image (without cutting off anything), thereby leaving some space either vertically or horizontally.

On the other hand, `background-size: cover;` will *fill the whole DIV* in a way that the shorter side of the image corresponds exactly to the length or height of the DIV (depending on the relation of the proportions between DIV and image) and the longer one is cut off on the sides or on top and bottom.

If you don't want a distorted image, those are the options you have.